# Image path with WebRootPath doesn't work. IHostingEnvironment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I woudl like to ask why IHostingEnvironment address doesn't work with images.

```
 private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;
```

it is working if i am going to delete,move or anyother  operation. i use this code

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(env.WebRootPath + "\\ClientFolder\\" + clientNameWithNoSpace);
```

BUT if i use the file name for image source, i can't see the images.

**Works: if @Model.ClientImageName =**

"\ClientFolder\Paul\ClientM.png"

**Deosn't work if it is:** "C:\Users\sari_\source\repos\MnMClientEF\MnMClientEF\wwwroot\ClientFolder\Paul\ClientM.png"

Comment: How do you use it as “image source”? Do you mean you try to put the path out to the browser? It doesn’t know about your paths, it needs a URL to the image.

Comment: I set image path like this <img src="@Model.ClientImageName" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this from teh Webserver, maybe security is getting in the way?

As Webservers usually run 24/7 and reachable from the internet, they are prime targets of hacking. So limiting their rights has become a integral part of security.

They usually each run under a seperate user. This user is given:

- Read rights in the Programm Folder
- Read rights in the Content Folder
- **maybe** write rights in a folder below content, for stuff like temporary files. But maybe you could just solve this with a HTTP handler instead?

If you do not do that, you end up with a hacker overwriting some code that redirects users comming from google to a pornographic page (real life example).

As the relative path works but the absolute does not, this might be the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Christopher. I am running my website in my computer and using Visual Studio. As you said, relative path is working but absolute path doesn't. I don't think problem is user rights because i am creating new folders, deleting files etc.. The only issue when it comes to use the absolute path as a source of image file in the cshtml file. But if it is safer, i will change my coding. thank you

Comment: @AliAzara If you did a standard installation, they might come with some degree of limited rights. It is just to common a requirement. There is a way to test it using relative paths, btw. An old rule of DOS times concerns the "." and ".." characters in paths. And that rule is still in effect. ".." says: "From the current point, go one folder level up". If your current directory is "C:\Users\sari_\source\repos\MnMClientEF\MnMClientEF\wwwroot\ClientFolder\Paul\", "..\..\..\" would have you work in "C:\Users\sari_\source\repos\MnMClientEF\MnMClientEF\"

Comment: Mostly "." and ".." were used if you did not want to change the working directory via "cd" when all you wanted to do was call one executeable that was in another folder. "." could help getting around the OS trying to be smart and using the paths rather then accepting a file was not there. But last I checked both still worked for relative paths in 2019.